# ios5 Xcode 4.2 scrollview self return error

Tags: return, scrollview, ios5, self

I made ​​a cartoon applications.
In ios4.3 perfectly well, but should not run ios5.

The error message "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'The view returned from viewForZoomingInScrollView: must be a subview of the scroll view. It can not be the scroll view itself."

```
- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView 
{    

    return self.scrollView;

}
```

If can't scroll view to self-return

Will replace all the code.

help me.

Answer (score 0):

This really seems to be a new "feature" of iOS5. xD
No i think it's really sensible to forbid returning and then resizing the scrollview itself.

To your solution:
If u just have ONE subview of your scrollview like an ImageView, GLKitView, MapView ... return it.
In case u have more then place all elements on a container like an UIView, place this on the scrollview and return the UIView.

This really should be it. I hope this works for you, too.

Kind regards. $h@rky

Edit: Any success until now?